# DisplayAlert methods only executed at the end of the method in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, compilation, activity-indicator

I'm writing a small Xamarin.Forms app and I try to do some actions like display alerts or show the Activity Indicator. However, everything what I wrote in my code is only executed at the end of the method, even the Activity Indicator, which is not the goal of course. The different alerts are even showing in LIFO, so the last one in the code appears first.

Here's the code in xaml.cs:

```
    private void btConnexion_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ai.IsRunning = true;
        IsBusy = true;
        LoginViewModel vm = (LoginViewModel)this.BindingContext;
        DisplayAlert(AppResources.Sorry, "Beginning", "Ok");

        try
        {
            DisplayAlert(AppResources.Sorry, "In the try", "Ok");

            if (vm.Valide())
            {
                Task t = Task.Run(async () => { await vm.AuthentificationAPI(); });
                if (!t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
                {
                    DisplayAlert(AppResources.Sorry, AppResources.TryAgainLater, "Ok");
                }

                if (t.IsCompleted)
                {
                    GetAllData();
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
                    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//main");

                }
            }
            else
                DisplayAlert(AppResources.Error, AppResources.MissingFieldsErrorMessage, "Ok");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert(AppResources.Sorry, AppResources.TryAgainLater + " (" + ex.Message + ")", "Ok");
        }
        finally
        {
            ai.IsRunning = false;
            DisplayAlert(AppResources.Sorry, "Finally", "Ok");


        }
        DisplayAlert(AppResources.Sorry, "After finally", "Ok");
    }
```

And where I call it in the .xaml:

```
        <Button Text="{x:Static resource:AppResources.Login}" 
                x:Name="btConnexion" 
                BackgroundColor="#AADC14" 
                Padding="0,0,0,0" 
                Clicked="btConnexion_Clicked"/>
```

I've put some alerts in the metohd, showing "In the try,", "Beginning", etc. If I debug the code step by step, all the alerts are only executed once at the end of the method, instead during the compilation. And in FILO, so the first one is "After finally", then "Finally", etc. And the Activity Indicator is not even showing, because of the same reason I suppose.

I don't know if it changes anything, but the xaml must be compiled as written in xaml.cs:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
```

Comment: Put await before DisplayAlert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small instance to change the internal state of the **DisplayAlert** and **ActivityIndicator** methods.

Here is cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //For DisplayAlert you only need to add await before the method.
    private async void btConnexion_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Button).Text == "test") 
        {
            await DisplayAlert("sorry", "try again later", "Ok");  
        }          
        await DisplayAlert("end", "end", "Ok");
    }

    //For ActivityIndicator, I use Task.Delay to make the effect clearer
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivityIndicator indicator = new ActivityIndicator();
        indicator.IsRunning = true;
        indicator.IsVisible = true;
        indicator.Color = Color.Black;
        stacklayout.Children.Add(indicator);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        indicator.IsRunning = false;
        indicator.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Here is xaml code:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout">
    <Button Text="test" 
            x:Name="btConnexion" 
            BackgroundColor="#AADC14" 
            Padding="0,0,0,0" 
            Clicked="btConnexion_Clicked"/>
    <Button Text="ActivityIndicator" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, indeed it works for me. But only thanks to the Task.Delay. Without this delay if I use your code it doesn't work. Or should I change something in my code?

Comment: It is just a delay. If you don’t add it, the code will run and end in an instant, so you won’t be able to see if it takes effect.

Comment: I mean that in my code I have to use an API which takes a few seconds, but even with that the AI is not showing (await vm.AuthentificationAPI(); )

Comment: I think you used await in your API request. It does not make the thread wait but starts a new thread.

Comment: Is the problem solved？

Comment: Hi, not yet solved. I'm still trying to understand why the await in my API would do that. Do I have to change the code which calls this API with the Task t?

Comment: I noticed that you used await vm.AuthentificationAPI();
When executing this line of code, the system will start a new thread to execute this line of code, and the main thread does not wait to continue execution, so you will see the method directly completes.

Comment: In the vm.AuthentificationAPI() method I've also also put IsBusy = true, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: The only thing that make the AI running is when I put IsBusy=true in the constructor of the ViewModel of the Login Page. But of course than the AI is always running. It just proves that the AI can be launched...

Comment: What I mean is to use vm.AuthentificationAPI() directly directly without opening a new thread.

Comment: Ok clear. I tried but I got an error message without it. But it's ok I give up, let's close this ticket.

Comment: The problem was solved by moving the AI at the end of the code, so it's not overwritten by the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Put await before the Display Alert like below

```
await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for the DisplayAlert, however not for the Activity Indicator. This only turns on at the end of the process. Any tips for that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was solved by putting the Activity Indicator at the end of the GridView, instead of the beginning, as below. So the AI was there, but not visible, because hidden in the background by the AbsoluteLayout.

```
</AbsoluteLayout>

<ActivityIndicator 
    IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
    Color="Red"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    />
```